# What is maximum number of files you can store in a tar archive under Solaris 11?

Tags: solaris, tar, zfs, limit, gnu

I need to store a large number of files (> 100,000) in a tar archive and have run into the error: **/bin/sh: /bin/tar: cannot execute [Arg list too long]**.

Are there limits with UNIX Solaris tar or GNU tar? Or, is this a ZFS issue? I am running Solaris 11.3 with ZFS.

Comment: How do you make the archive?

Comment: Appearances are a limit to tar’s argument list, not contents.

Comment: As the error seems to be related to the number of arguments that have been passed on the command line, I think it would be useful to see what was the command you used for this purpose.

Comment: The error message is from `/bin/sh` (failing on `execve`), not from `tar` (as you can guess). If you replace `tar` by `ls -l` you'll get the *same* error

Answer (score 7):

This is not a limitation of tar. You are exceeding the maximum size of arguments that can be passed to a program. If the list of file names is available in a file, then you can use GNU tar's `-T` option:

```
tar -c -f output.tar -T filelist.txt
```

Tar can also receive the file list from standard input by using `-` as the file name. For example, if you want to create an archive containing all files and subdirectories of `mydir`, you can pass the output of `find` to tar:

```
find mydir | tar -c -f output.tar -T -
```

Comment: *You are exceeding the maximum size of arguments that can be passed to a program.* To be specific, that's likely a `sh` limit.  `csh` has a much larger limit.  Running `csh<enter>host% tar -cvf tarfile.tar *` can work when running the same command under `sh` fails with an `arg list is too long` error.

Comment: I've usually had the issue with the `csh` and better luck with the `sh` shell for this.  But in this case I think creating an include file with the `-I` option would work better than passing the files as args.

Comment: Please read the `tar` man page before answerig questions, the `-T` option switches on **Trusted Extensions** and this is definitely not what you like. You probably ment the `-I` option...or did you refer to GNU tar? Then you should know that the official name for GNU tar is `gtar`,

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, the issue is (probably) the length of the command
and not the size of the archive. 
You should be able to do

```
tar cf tarfile file001 file002 … file100
tar uf tarfile file101 file102 … file200
tar uf tarfile file201 file202 … file300
                  ︙
```

Alternatively, do

```
tar cf tarfile file001
```

to create the archive,
and then

```
tar cf tarfile         file002 … file100
tar uf tarfile file101 file102 … file200
tar uf tarfile file201 file202 … file300
                  ︙
```

(possibly with `xargs`) to add to it.

Comment: Just be aware that updating a tar file with the number of entries in question can be excruciatingly slow.